# SQL on ORACLE APEX 5.x

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am attempting to update the time on a table called application_history, each of the column names are listed in the 'CASE' section where I attempt to set the 'status' to the column name. I then later try to use that column to try and insert the time in that column.
Here is what I have attempted, bearing in  mind that I have no idea what triggers limitations are.

```
create or replace TRIGGER update_application_history AFTER UPDATE ON application
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  status VARCHAR(35);
BEGIN 
  CASE
    WHEN old.application_status LIKE 'Application Withdrawn' THEN SET status = 'APPLICATION_WITHDRAWN'
    WHEN old.application_status LIKE 'Applicant Accepted Offer' THEN SET status = 'APPLICANT_ACCEPTED_OFFER'
    WHEN old.application_status LIKE 'Applicant Declined Offer' THEN SET status = 'APPLICANT_DECLINED_OFFER'
    WHEN old.application_status LIKE 'Applicant Invited for Assessment' THEN SET status = 'INVITED_TO_ASSESMENT_CENTRE'
    WHEN old.application_status LIKE 'Applicant Invited for Interview' THEN SET status = 'INVITED_FOR_INTERVIEW'
    WHEN old.application_status LIKE 'Applicant Offered Position' THEN SET status = 'APPLICANT_OFFERED_POSITION'
    WHEN old.application_status LIKE 'Applicant Rejected'THEN SET status = 'APPLICANT_REJECTED'
  END
UPDATE application_history
SET status = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
WHERE old.arn LIKE arn
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can not use dynamic column names in PL/SQL (at least not like that)
2. Assignment of values to variables is handled with the `:=` operator in PL/SQL.
3. Don't use `LIKE` when you really should use `=`
4. Why do you store `sysdate` as a `varchar2` in the application_history table? Maybe those columns are indeed of type `varchar2`, but if they only store dates then please consider changing that to `date`.

All in all, your trigger should look something like this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER update_application_history AFTER UPDATE ON application
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  CASE
    WHEN :old.application_status = 'Application Withdrawn' 
    THEN 
      UPDATE application_history
      SET APPLICATION_WITHDRAWN = sysdate
      WHERE :old.arn = arn;
    WHEN :old.application_status = 'Applicant Accepted Offer' 
    THEN 
      UPDATE application_history
      SET APPLICANT_ACCEPTED_OFFER = sysdate
      WHERE :old.arn = arn;
    -- you get the point... add the rest here
    END CASE;
END;
```

Comment: I shall use := in future, in regradas to the application history, I tried to use date, but it only shows the date in the columns and I need it show time as well, I've tried changing the NSL default and various other methods, but because it's on application express it dfoesnt change the format of DATE. Eventually I gave up and use the VARCHAR alternative.

Comment: @Zachary `sysdate` ALWAYS stores the time as well, you can check that when you do a `select to_char(applicant_accepted_offer, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from application_history`. Remember, how a date is *stored* is something totally different than how it is *displayed*.

Comment: Any ideas on how I can get it to display properly in the report? I understand that the time is there but have no idea how to display it properly. Again thank you for the quick response

Comment: Brilliant, it's been a pleasure.